# C# Console Application Does NOT read from the command line, as it should

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, command-line, command-line-arguments

I have spent a good while trying to get this simple code to read from the command line:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if(args.Length > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; ++i)
                    System.Console.WriteLine(args[i]);
            }
            else System.Console.WriteLine("NO COMMAND INPUT DETECTED");
            System.Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

When typing the command:

ConsoleApplication3.application "pleasework"

I get the following message in the command line:

NO COMMAND INPUT DETECTED

indicating that the command line is not working properly. Any thoughts? I am very bad with Visual Studio (this is 2012) so I imagine there is some special property I need to change or something ridiculous.

Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. Where are you entering the command?

Comment: To avoid any UAC issues--have you tried running cmd.exe as Administrator?

Comment: I'm running this from both the VS 2012 command line and the regular windows command line.

Comment: Just ran cmd.exe as admin with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(args.Length);

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to go to my command prompt and run:

```
C:\ProjectPath\ConsoleApplication1\bin\debug\ConsoleApplivation1.exe "Test" "Test2"
```

With a result of:

```
2
```

***Edit:*** It looks like you are running a ClickOnce Console Application. This complicates what you want to do, but it isn't impossible. Here are several resources that discuss this particular issue:

[Processing Command Line Arguments in an Offline ClickOnce Application](http://developingfor.net/2010/06/23/processing-command-line-arguments-in-an-offline-clickonce-application/)

[Harvesting ClickOnce Command Line Arguments](http://briannoyes.net/2004/08/10/HarvestingClickOnceCommandLineArguments.aspx)

[How to pass arguments to an offline ClickOnce application](http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/03/21/how-to-pass-arguments-to-an-offline-clickonce-application/)

Comment: I did ConsoleApplication3.application "pleasework" "yo" 

for a result of: 

0

Could this be due to the fact that my file builds into an application and not an executable?

Comment: Are you publishing the console app as a ClickOnce application? Or just building/debuging it? Because when I publish a ClickOnce console application, launching it via the .application does NOT work for me.

Comment: Yeah I was publishing as a one-click. Which alternatives work? I am INCREDIBLY visual-studio ignorant and only use it when forced to so specific recommendations would be great.

Comment: I would recommend not using "Publish". I would just build it and take the executable from the bin directory where your project is at. If you don't change any project settings, it'll be C:\<Your Project Path>\ ConsoleApplication3\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication3.exe

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be okay. 
You're probably not passing the argument *properly*.

Take the following steps:

Right-Click on your Project **=>** Properties **=>** Debug **=>** insert "Pleasework" into the command line arguments **=>** save and debug your code step-by-step.

[image]

And you'll see:

[image]

Comment: @Erroldactyl Very weird, can you send the exact command that you're executing on the command-prompt or in any other form?

Comment: @Erroldactyl Are you Run As Administrator?

Comment: I am not sure if I was doing so now, but I just ran the command prompt as an admin and ran the code unsuccessfully through that prompt.

Comment: @Erroldactyl Create a new simple console application and see if it's also happening.